# What is the meaning of return $request->post(); in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

what is the meaning of **return $request->post();** in laravel ? Please help me

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->post();
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request `post()` method

For example consider you have following data in request

```
[
        'username'=>'John lobo',
        "dob"=>'10/10/1990',
        'address'=>[
            'city'=>'London',
            'country'=>'Uk'
        ]
    ]
```

1.If no params passed to post() method then it return all data from request.

```
return $request->post();
```

Output will be

```
{
"username": "John lobo",
"dob": "10/10/1990",
"address": {
"city": "London",
"country": "Uk"
}
}
```

2.if first param passed to post() method then it will return only that keys value .For example i have passed

`return $request->post('username');`

then output will be `John lobo`

3.if first param passed to post() method is `invalid key` or doesn't exist in request  then it will not `throw error` instead it will `return null`

4.Suppose if you want to set default value if its null then you can pass second `param`

```
return $request->post('username',"John Lobo");
```

5.In request post method you cant access `nested key directly` for example

```
return $request->post('address.city');
```

it wont throw `error` instead it will return `null`

But if you consider `$request->input()` then it works exactly same as `$request->post()` but  one difference is ,It will return nested value directly instead of empty

```
return request()->input('address.city');
```

The output is `London`

If `request` contains `file` then both request `input` and `post` return location of the path like below instead of file object.In that case `$request->all()` is good way

```
 "file" => "I:\xampp\tmp\phpB84E.tmptest"
```